# Date Select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I want to use an input field and beside the input field should be displayed an date select field in which the user can choose the date and this date will then be filled in the input field. Do you know an easy solution without using prototype?

Thanks for your help,

Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the date_select form helper?
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Comment: Yeah thats quite simple and stupid easy. Thanks for this advise.